# ValueError at /spotify/liked/: Cannot assign 'some value': "Liked_Songs.track_name" must be a "Profile" instance

Tags: django, django-models

So I have users whose profiles are automatically created after user creation with the help of `Django Signals`

`models.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Meta:
   db_table = "Profile"


class Liked_Songs(models.Model):
   track_name = models.ForeignKey(Profile , on_delete= models.CASCADE , related_name="track")
   artiste_name= models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete= models.CASCADE , related_name="artiste")
   album_name = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name= "album")

class Meta:
    db_table = "Liked Songs"

def __str__(self):
    return self.track_name
```

1. In this `Liked_Songs` model, my `views.py` accesses an API and my aim is to allow all fields in that model to be populated with data from the API. So there will be multiple `track_name` etc received. So each Profile can have many `track names` etc. Is the `ForeignKey` appropriate for this?
2. However, when I use this route below, i get an error I have stated in the problem description.
   `Views.py`

   ```
   def liked(request):
   try:
     if "access_token" in request.session:
        sp = Spotify(auth = request.session.get("access_token"))
        liked = sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=30)['items']
     for idx, item in enumerate(liked):
        track = item['track']["name"]
        artist= item["track"]["artists"][0]["name"]
        album = item["track"]["album"]["name"]

        Liked_Songs.objects.create(
            track_name= track,
            artiste_name= artist,
            album_name = album
        ).save()

    except SpotifyException:
        return redirect(reverse("login"))
   ```

Comment: what is the track it is id or name

Comment: it is the name of the track @Ankit

Answer (score 0):

you are storing profile id in track so you cannot pass name in it so try to pass profile id in it
try this `track_name_id = profile_id`